# Entity Framework eager loading with include not working

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6, eager-loading

Domain Models

```
public class InvestmentSession
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("CreatedById")]
    public virtual User CreatedBy { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int CreatedById { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public virtual Instrument Instrument { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<SessionUser> SessionUsers { get; set; }
}
public class SessionUser
{
    [Key, Column(Order = 1), ForeignKey("InvestmentSession")]
    public int InvestmentSession_Id { get; set; }

    [Key, Column(Order = 2), ForeignKey("User")]
    public int User_Id { get; set; }

    public virtual InvestmentSession InvestmentSession { get; set; }

    [InverseProperty("UserSessions")]
    public virtual User User { get; set; }

    public decimal? TotalProfitLoss { get; set; }
}

public class User
{
    public User()
    {

    }

    public User(string name, string email)
    {
        Name = name;
        Email = email;
        IsActive = 1;
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [Required, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed)]
    public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int IsActive { get; set; }

    [JsonIgnore]
    public virtual ICollection<SessionUser> UserSessions { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Role_Id")]
    [JsonIgnore]
    public virtual Role Role { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int Role_Id { get; set; }
}
```

I am trying to get an active session by Id and Include SessionUsers

```
public InvestmentSession GetActiveSession(int id)
    {
        try
        {
            var now = DateTime.UtcNow;
            return Context.InvestmentSession.Include(s => s.SessionUsers).FirstOrDefault(i => i.Id == id && now >= i.StartDate && now < i.EndDate);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            throw new Exception(e.Message);
        }
    }

foreach (var sessionUser in session.SessionUsers)
            {
                var key = session.Id + sessionUser.User.Email + Constants.TRADER_PERFORMANCE_CACHE_IDENTIFIER;
                var traderPerformance = RedisStore.GetValue<TraderLivePerformanceDto>(key);
                if (traderPerformance != null)
                {
                    activeSessionData.Performances.Add(traderPerformance);
                }
                else
                {
                    var newTraderPerformance = new TraderLivePerformanceDto
                    {
                        traderId = sessionUser.User_Id,
                        traderName = sessionUser.User.Name,
                        initialCash = session.InitialCash,
                        availableCash = session.InitialCash,
                        portfolioValue = session.InitialCash
                    };
                    RedisStore.StoreValue(key, newTraderPerformance, session.EndDate);
                    activeSessionData.Performances.Add(newTraderPerformance);
                }
            }
```

However iterating over session.SessionUsers is extremly slow, adding a breakpoint in the loop is causing the code to go into expection "***ExecuteReader requires an open and available Connection. The connection's current state is closed***" so I am assuming it still querying the DB for SessionUsers.

Comment: `adding a breakpoint in the loop is causing the code to go into expection` The code you have shown us doesn't have a loop in it.

Comment: Are you using `Context` in another method? How do you instantiate that? Is That a singleton?

Comment: added loop code

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue, accessing sessionUser.User in the loop.

Changed my query to

```
return Context.InvestmentSession.Include(s => s.SessionUsers.Select(su => su.User)).FirstOrDefault(i => i.Id == id && now >= i.StartDate && now < i.EndDate);
```